# How can I capture a table row press action in Swift WatchKit?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, watchkit, ibaction

I currently have a table with some dynamic rows.  When I run the probject the rows display on the screen and even have a press animation but xcode won't let me wire up the table row as an IBAction to its controller.  I can't use a segue in this instance, it needs to be like a button press but preferably on the whole table rown I'd rather not insert a button into it.  Any help appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to override the `table:didSelectRowAtIndex` function. It is a method on `WKInterfaceController`.

```
override func table(table: WKInterfaceTable, didSelectRowAtIndex rowIndex: Int) {
    // Handle row selection
}
```

Comment: Worked beautifully - thanks.  Just to clarify the table identifier: super.table(tableName, didSelectRowAtIndex: rowIndex) to target your table

Comment: @Evernoob - I removed the call to `super` altogether. Apple's sample code doesn't make a call to `super`.

Comment: Great - just tested it and yes that works too and is a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Updated to swift 3.1:

There is no need to use WKInterfaceTable because now the function is located inside the UITableViewController.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let ren : Int = indexPath.row

    print ("Row \(ren)")
}
```